Knit to PDF in Rmarkdown
My graph looks messed when I knit to PDF.
But when I run the code in chunk in rmarkdown. it looks okay.
can anyone advise?
below is my code.
#plotting data set "a" in a bar graph

ggplot(a, aes(Year, Returns, fill = Country))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")+
  labs(caption = "Federal Reserve Bank of St Louis",
       x = "Year",
       y = "Returns (Millions of Dollars)")+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greys")+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 200000), breaks = seq(0, 200000, 50000))

I have tried many times.enter image description here
